Async producer/consumer running serially
I'm getting started with asyncio and created this:
import asyncio

async def handle_data(q):
    while (item := await q.get()) is not None:
        print(f'Consuming {item}')

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    consumer = asyncio.create_task(handle_data(q))

    for k in range(10):
        print(f'Producing {k}')
        await q.put(k)

    await q.put(None)
    await consumer

asyncio.run(main())

The script outputs
Producing 0
Producing 1
Producing 2
Producing 3
Producing 4
Producing 5
Producing 6
Producing 7
Producing 8
Producing 9
Consuming 0
Consuming 1
Consuming 2
Consuming 3
Consuming 4
Consuming 5
Consuming 6
Consuming 7
Consuming 8
Consuming 9

Why is the code running synchronously?

You could try a couple of things (but please read the Note at the end for why you might not want to try either of these things in a real world example):

Use asyncio.sleep(0), which gives another running a task to get dispatched:

import asyncio

async def handle_data(q):
    while (item := await q.get()) is not None:
        print(f'Consuming {item}')

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    consumer = asyncio.create_task(handle_data(q))

    for k in range(10):
        print(f'Producing {k}')
        await q.put(k)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)  # Allow another task to get dispatched

    await q.put(None)
    await consumer

asyncio.run(main())

On my desktop I get:
Producing 0
Consuming 0
Producing 1
Consuming 1
Producing 2
Consuming 2
Producing 3
Consuming 3
Producing 4
Consuming 4
Producing 5
Consuming 5
Producing 6
Consuming 6
Producing 7
Consuming 7
Producing 8
Consuming 8
Producing 9
Consuming 9


If the above does not work for you, then specify a queue capacity of 1. This will block main until another task empties the queue:

import asyncio

async def handle_data(q):
    while (item := await q.get()) is not None:
        print(f'Consuming {item}')

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue(1)  # maxsize is 1
    consumer = asyncio.create_task(handle_data(q))

    for k in range(10):
        print(f'Producing {k}')
        await q.put(k)

    await q.put(None)
    await consumer

asyncio.run(main())

Note
I am not sure what this accomplishes for you. main and handle_data are still running essentially synchronously with one another and you are getting no overlap in processing given the code you have posted. Suppose handle_data did some relatively long I/O processing such as retrieving a URL from some web site and there were several such URL's that needed retrieving. If I had some number of URL's to retrieve and you wanted to use a specific number of concurrent tasks to do the retrieving, then I would want to be putting the URLs to the queue as quickly as I could and not waiting for a URL to be retrieved from the queue before putting the next one.
import asyncio

async def fetch_url(q):
    while (url := await q.get()) is not None:
        # Code to fetch data from the url using aiohttp, for example:
        ...

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()

    urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4']
    n_tasks = 2
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_url(q)) for _ in range(n_tasks)]

    for url in urls:
        await q.put(url)

    for _ in range(n_tasks):
        await q.put(None)

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())

But if you wanted N tasks to retrieve N URLs, then you would want to code this without using a queue at all:
import asyncio

async def fetch_url(url):
    # Code to fetch data from the url wuing aiohttp, for example:
    ...

async def main():
    urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4']

    await asyncio.gather(*(fetch_url(url) for url in urls))

asyncio.run(main())

